# build opencv with ffmpeg support

Tags: python, video, ffmpeg, opencv, video-capture-card

I read nearly all of the questions about this subject but I didn't solve it. I installed OpenCV in the virtual environment a lot of times when trying to solve this problem. P**roblem is that: "cv2.videoCapture() return always false".**

I built the OpenCV with **-D WITH_FFMPEG=ON** option and it would finish successfully and the result that about FFmpeg was seemed to be OK.

Also, when I run "**make -j8**" command, it finished with no problem. So I thought everything will be OK. When I tried to check FFmpeg support with this command: `python -c "import cv2; print(cv2.getBuildInformation())" | grep -i FFmpeg` it gave me NO result.

I installed OpenCV with following [these stpes](https://www.learnopencv.com/install-opencv3-on-ubuntu/). I also tried to find if FFMPEG supports codec for decoding AVC encoded files. `ffmpeg -codecs | grep -i avc` and, the output is :

> DEV.LS h264 H.264 / AVC / MPEG-4 AVC / MPEG-4 part 10 (decoders: h264
>   h264_cuvid ) (encoders: h264_nvenc nvenc nvenc_h264 ) D.A.L. avc On2
>   Audio for Video Codec (decoders: on2avc )

I didn't understand why FFmpeg has seemed "YES" when I have building OpenCV at that time has given "NO" result with cv2.getBuildInformation().

```
(cv_env)➜  cv_env pkg-config --modversion opencv
3.2.0
(cv_env)➜  cv_env python                        
Python 2.7.6 (default, Oct 26 2016, 20:30:19) 
[GCC 4.8.4] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import cv2
>>> cv2.__version__
'3.3.0'

(cv_env)➜  cv_env python -c "import cv2; print(cv2.getBuildInformation())" | grep -i ffmpeg
    FFMPEG:                      NO
(cv_env)➜  cv_env python
Python 2.7.6 (default, Oct 26 2016, 20:30:19) 
[GCC 4.8.4] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import cv2
>>> cv2.__file__
'/opt/cv_env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cv2/cv2.so'

(cv_env)➜  cv_env python3
Python 3.4.3 (default, Nov 28 2017, 16:41:13) 
[GCC 4.8.4] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import cv2
>>> cv2.__version__
'3.3.0'
>>> cv2.__file__
'/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/cv2/cv2.cpython-34m.so'
```

Also, I didn't remember which steps I applied (for python2 or python3). For that reason, I added cv2 versions and paths.
I checked cv2.**version** after import cv2, and it seems '3.3.0' also pip freeze result like that. I cloned OpenCV from github like these steps which I gave the url to my question. After following these steps, version should be 3.3.1 but it still seems 3.3.0. If I imported prebuilt opencv, how can I fix it? In my virtual env has just one OpenCV directory and I think it is the last one which I installed.

It sounds like I am launching Python2, which has the other version of OpenCV installed, not 3.3.1. 
How can I fix it?

Comment: This is not a question related to Ubuntu. You might find more help if you go to OpenCV support forum.

Comment: @darksky I read this problem just Linux/ubuntu